# Selenium IDE: Unexpected Exception: ... selenium-core/scripts/selenium-browserbot.js, lineNumber -> 228

Tags: testing, selenium, ide

I'm using Selenium IDE 1.8.1 with Firefox 14.

I see this exception:

```
[error] Unexpected Exception: fileName -> chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-browserbot.js, lineNumber -> 228
```

when running the following:

```
<tr>
    <td>assertElementPresent</td>
    <td>//a[text()='! selenium test customer']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>//a[text()='! selenium test customer']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

As you can see the element is present (otherwise the assert would fail halting the test), so I can't figure out what's going wrong. Anyone got any clues?

**[edit]** It seems to only occur if I run the test at the fastest speed. If I slow it down, the error doesn't occur. That's not really a solution though, as running the entire suite at half speed is way too slow.

Comment: I tried to track the call to the specified line of code and spot no obvious way for it to fail. It seems to be dug deeper / appear only sometimes, somewhere. I also found no similar bug on Selenium bug repository, so I guess the best thing you can do is [report it](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/entry) with all your information (and a reproducible testcase, if possible) and hope for it to be fixed some time soon.

Comment: Will do if no one actually solves it in a day or two. The Selenium devs are here, too, you know ;-).

Comment: Reported as  [issue 4335](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4335)

Comment: See my answer below.  I don't think Unexpected Exception is the right response from Selenium, but that may be because it returns true/false and that response is not being processed (at least according to the snippet provided).  I think waitForElement may be a better option for what I am GUESSING you are trying to do with this snippet.   Add a timeout to wait THEN assert.  You want to give the server & DOM time to process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a bug with Selenium. Did you file it?

Answer (score 0):

With Selenium IDE I have found that using waitForElement just before the clickAndWait call seems to work best.

assertElementPresent simply returns FALSE if it is not present, true if it is present.  It is meant to be used in an if/else construct to take a specified path.

Replace your assertElementPresent with waitForElement and you may have better results.